# The meaning of the universal quantification

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, parametric-polymorphism

I am trying to understand the meaning of the universal quantification from the following page http://dev.stephendiehl.com/hask/#universal-quantification.

I am not sure, if I understand this sentence correctly

> The essence of universal quantification is that we can express
>   functions which operate the same way for a set of types and whose
>   function behavior is entirely determined only by the behavior of all
>   types in this span.

Let`s take the function from the example:

```
-- ∀a. [a]
example1 :: forall a. [a]
example1 = []
```

What I can do with the function `example1` is, to use every functions, that is defined for List type.

But I did not get the exactly purpose of the universal quantification in Haskell.

Comment: `example1` there isn't a function. It's just the empty list. The point being made is that this is really a "polymorphic constant" (much like number literals are), it can have type `[a]` for *any* type `a`. You don't actually need the `forall a.` there (or in any of the examples on the page you linked to), because it's understood implicitly by Haskell. But you do need explicit `forall`s once you get into Rank 2 types (and higher).

Comment: Note the warning just before that section. Beware that keyword `forall` appears in two utterly different contexts of a type signature (and this confuses the heck out of me): either it's universal quantification, and in that case it's usually optional; or it's existential quantification/`Rank 2` (or higher) types, and in that case it's required.

Comment: @RobinZigmond personally, I prefer "polymorphic constant *definition*". I.e. it is a definition capable of defining an empty list `[] :: [a]` constant for any specific choice of `a`. (or should it then be `A`?..).

Answer (score 1):

I need a collection of numbers, and I need to be able to easily insert into the middle of the list, so I decide on making a linked list. Being a savvy Hask-- programmer (Hask-- being the variant of Haskell that does not have universal quantification!), I quickly whip up a type and a length function without trouble:

```
data IntLinkedList = IntNil | IntCons Int IntLinkedList

length_IntLinkedList :: IntLinkedList -> Int
length_IntLinkedList IntNil = 0
length_IntLinkedList (IntCons _ tail) = 1 + length_IntLinkedList tail
```

Later I realize it would be handy to have a variant type that can store numbers not quite as big as 1 and not quite as small as 0. No problem...

```
data FloatLinkedList = FloatNil | FloatCons Float FloatLinkedList

length_FloatLinkedList :: FloatLinkedList -> Int
length_FloatLinkedList FloatNil = 0
length_FloatLinkedList (FloatCons _ tail) = 1 + length_FloatLinkedList tail
```

*Boy* that code looks awfully familiar! And if, later, I discover it would be nice to have a variant that can store `String`s I am once again left copying and pasting the exact same code, and tweaking the exact same places that are specific to the contained type. Wouldn't it be nice if there were a way to just cook up a linked list once and for all that could contain elements of any single type, and a length function that worked uniformly no matter what elements it had? After all, our length functions above didn't even care what values the elements had. In Haskell, this is exactly what universal quantification gives you: a way to write a single function which works with an entire collection of types.

Here's how it looks:

```
data LinkedList a = Nil | Cons a (LinkedList a)

length_LinkedList :: forall a. LinkedList a -> Int
length_LinkedList Nil = 0
length_LinkedList (Cons _ tail) = 1 + length_LinkedList tail
```

The `forall` says that this function for all variants of linked lists -- linked lists of `Int`s, linked lists of `Float`s, linked lists of `String`s, linked lists of functions that take FibbledyGibbets and return linked lists of tuples of Grazbars and WonkyNobbers, ...

How nice! Now instead of separate `IntLinkedList` and `FloatLinkedList` types, we can just use `LinkedList Int` and `LinkedList Float` for that, and `length_LinkedList`, implemented once, works for both.

Comment: this leaves the door open to a question like, 'So why shouldn't I be able to have a list of Ints, Floats and Strings all mixed together if all I'm going to do is measure its length?'.

Comment: @WillNess Certainly! And that's the purpose of existential quantification, a thing that also exists in Haskell. But zero_coding asked about universal quantification, not existential...

Comment: I was aiming more at the essence of polymorphic typing, why the lists must be  homogeneous, etc. Was hoping you cold shed some light on that. I don't need existential types to measure the length. or to zip. it probably goes to the heart of static vs dynamic typing...?

Comment: @WillNess A koan that may focus your thinking on this topic: you don't need types at all, for any algorithm. What good are they, then?

Comment: I understand the HM attitude on this, but surely there are more than two edge points on that spectrum. imagine `let xs=[(1,True),("2",False)] in (map fst $ filter snd xs, map fst $ filter (not.snd) xs)`. the end result is well typed, makes sense. if list manipulation functions should only perform structural manipulations, why should they concern themselves with lists' homogeneity? HM says, OK, but such lists won't make sense *afterwards* anyway. My example shows, they *could be*. Traits of involved values could be gradually discoverable, as the program progresses... etc.

Comment: I'll give you another example. `sieve (x:xs) = x:sieve (remove (multsof x) xs)` admits *two pairs* of implementations of `remove` and `multsof` going together, each pair making sense in its own unique way (thus, with radically different types). HM wants the types known upfront, so forces us to choose too early. but `sieve` could conceivably have a "type" *before* the *implementation* choice was made. (motivation: write executable specification, let a compiler choose specific implementation (say, optimizing for space, or speed, or clarity of error traces, etc.).)

Comment: (...contd) it could even choose arrays instead of lists, if all I had in the end was `main = readLn >>= \n -> print $ sieve [2..100] !! n`. a feat unimaginable with HM. /empty musings, huh... well, that's what I was expecting of Haskell when I first learned about it... all that hype!.. i.e. why should I the app programmer ever need to know about lists or arrays or B-trees or finger trees etc. Let the compiler analyze my code and choose the appropriate implementation according to whatever option is chosen... or recompile constantly in actual run-time according to the app's use patterns.

Comment: @WillNess That's quite a rant! I'm not sure where it leaves us, though. I'm tempted to suggest you open an SO question yourself and use the expanded space to give your perspective more fully, but... honestly it would probably get closed as "too broad" faster than an answer could get written, hah! I do have some thoughts, but I also wonder: is this still a grudge you harbor against Haskell, or are these mostly musings on the thoughts a beginner *could* be having coming into this question, or what? How are you hoping people will engage with this?

Comment: No, not a grudge. I've long since come to grips with Haskell being yet another programming language. I was just hoping for some light from you on these kinds of subtleties with type systems and the reasons for this or that decision taken in Haskell's. if there's anything that wold fit in an SO answer, that is. :) Coming initially from a dynamic world (i.e. Lisp) to Haskell, the lists homogeneity requirement was not at all clear to me, for a long time. so maybe this needs some expounding on, for like minded beginners's sake. :)

Comment: @WIll Ness, you could try asking on cs.stackexchange -- that's for more 'theoretical'/less code-oriented questions. My short answer is: Haskell is a compiled language, not interpreted like LISP; therefore it's statically-typed. With all the types known at compile time, that makes for strong abilities to optimise to a performance comparable with low-level languages like C. Contrast that early 1990's when Haskell started, the main thing Functional Programming was famous for was: nice theory but terrible performance/might use that in the classroom but not in real life.